# how to intall IHP on windows using ubuntu 20.04

Tags: windows, installation, ihp

I tried to install IHP on windows using the doc : https://ihp.digitallyinduced.com/Guide/installation.html

I installed :

- WSL
- Ubuntu 20.04
- Made : sudo update and sudo upgrade then sudo apt install git curl make xdg-utils -y
- Created : sudo mkdir -p /etc/nix
- Created : /etc/nix/nix.conf
- Installed IHP : curl -L https://nixos.org/nix/install | sh

Everything ok up to here.

Then I started a project :

- ihp-new blog
- Cachix : there were a pb to install cachix, but I tried a second time. Everything seems ok
- Run ./start and I have the following error :

`propagated-build-inputs: /nix/store/z856a8dzgp75jaswjsh0bw77svsd9jxh-wai-cors-0.2.7/nix-support/propagated-build-inputs ghc-pkg: Couldn't open database /nix/store/8dcwfqglr314g6rbygnnypgg32mjbbfc-ghc-8.10.4-with-packages/lib/ghc-8.10.4/package.conf.d for modification: {handle: /nix/store/8dcwfqglr314g6rbygnnypgg32mjbbfc-ghc-8.10.4-with-packages/lib/ghc-8.10.4/package.conf.d/package.cache.lock}: hLock: invalid argument (Invalid argument) builder for '/nix/store/1z2rk8z8zjss5cgcdxks8scx29jw6dq3-ghc-8.10.4-with-packages.drv' failed with exit code 1 error: build of '/nix/store/1z2rk8z8zjss5cgcdxks8scx29jw6dq3-ghc-8.10.4-with-packages.drv' failed`

I am completely new with Nix.

Any help should be nice.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are running ihp-new inside the Ubuntu filesystem! I was running into errors like this while trying to initialize a project in the Windows filesystem.

Comment: I created a project in /home/myhome. I tried also in a special directory /ihp. I am not in windows filesystem : /mnt/c. I still have the same error. Any ideas ?